# Is there a way to make this regex more efficient?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a bounce (NDR) handler.

Basically this regex pulls out an email address out of a piece of text.

```
[a-z0-9-._%+=!$~]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,15}
```

Some NDR have a lot of text in it and requires a ton of steps according to regex101.com depending where the email is located in the block of test. Is their a better regex expression, that can be used to make it more efficient at searching for the email in the NDR?

Comment: regex101.com steps are not a direct proof the regex will be too slow in your code. Try it in the target environment first.

Comment: It's not that it's slow, I'm more concerned with CPU Utilization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backtracking is what eats your CPU usually. The easiest way to solve it - is to write such regex, that can identify not only the tokens you are looking for, but also invalid tokens. In this way you can elliminate backtracking and make it all much faster.

However, finding such token depends on input text, basically, you need to find a regexp that:

- Covers as much as possible of "invalid" text
- Backtracks as rarely as possible

If your NDR is plain text (as it usually is) then probably something like this should be optimal enough:

```
(?:[^@]+\s)
```

Basically it's a non-capturing group of anything that's not a "@" followed by a space. This means, it will pretty much "eat" all your text up to the email address forbidding the regex engine to backtrack onto those matched groups.

Full regex would look like this:

```
(?:[^@]+\s)([a-z0-9-._%+=!$~]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,15})
```

Compare it in regex debugger at regex101.com to see the difference in how it works.

**Edit:**
A more appropriate solution would be to check for `[^a-z0-9-._%+=!$~]` instead of `\s`. So the final version would be:

```
(?:[^@]+[^a-z0-9-._%+=!$~])([a-z0-9-._%+=!$~]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,15})
```

**Sidenote:**
If you are considering optimizing such a simple regex query, there is a big chance that regex is not the right tool for you. Throw in some simple custom code and it will be much faster and easier understand and debug than some monstrous regex. And the more you try to optimize it - the bigger monstrosity it will become.

Comment: Why a lazy star quantifier `(...)*?`?

Comment: When you have pattern `( test )*` and apply it onto input `. test nottest`, then it will try to match the pattern on the `nottest` part twice. First time it fails, and then greedily tries to match again. When you put a lazy star quantifier - it will only try to match it until it fails, which saves you one backtrack operation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. But by my comment I didn't mean why not a greedy quantifier instead, but I meant why a quantifier at all.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, fixed.

Comment: As with any jump ahead scheme, in the worst case if there is no email, this will quadruple the time taken to not find anything. This applies also to having an email somewhere, but if between the last email and the end of text is large, same applies.

Comment: Bezmax, thanks for the solution. I tested the timings on myregextester.com - Night and day difference in speed. This is what I was looking for. You Rock!.

Comment: You are welcome, but also beware of my sidenote and sln's comments. I only gave an example of how it could possibly work much faster - but if the input is "unfortunate" - all goes to hell and processing time quadruples or even worse. If you find yourself microoptimizing each of various inputs - then it's better and easier to just write a simple finite-state machine based parser for finding those emails.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that, with super-long TEXT input it way worse, with shorter text, it's way faster.  Just did some testing with large text data 25 secs vs .0017 sec.